# URL.Action includes id when constructing URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url.action

I'm using ASP.Net MVC.  Here's my code snippets from a controller named Course:

```
public ActionResult List(int id)
{
    var viewmodel.ShowUrl = Url.Action("Show", "Course");


    ...
}

public ActionResult Show(int id)
{
  ...
}
```

viewmodel.ShowUrl picks up whatever the value is of the "id" parameter.  So viewmodel.ShowUrl becomes "/Course/Show/151" (value of id is 151);  I want to be able to set the id part on the client based on user interaction.  I want the value of viewmodel.ShowUrl to be "/Course/Show".

This seems like a bug to me.  I'm not telling Url.Action to include an id value.  It's doing it on its own.  If I want to set the id value then I would do something like this:

```
var viewmodel.ShowUrl = Url.Action("Show", "Course", new {id = somevalue});
```

So, how do you prevent MVC from adding the id value?  I can hardcode viewmodel.ShowUrl to "/Course/Show" but that seems to be a kludgy solution.  Thanks.

Comment: I cant remeber exactly but the `Routedata` is on `ViewData` and that's why it's passed. I think you can do `Url.Action("Show", "Course", new {});` or empty the `RouteData` on `ViewData` object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing in your routing, you're not specifying that id is an optional parameter. Here's the default route in a sample project.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } //Parameter defaults
);
```

Note the inclusion of `id = UrlParameter.Optional`. Without that, you'd get the behavior you're describing because it thinks the id is mandatory.

On a side note, if your Show action doesn't always have an id then it should be nullable or provide a default.

```
public ActionResult Show(int? id)
public ActionResult Show(int id = 0)
```

Otherwise you'll get an error when you try loading the url without the id parameter.

Answer (score 35):

Just came across the same problem and so you know, you can also just use an empty string:

```
@Url.Action("Show", "Course", new { id = "" })
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben. This is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is old, but I found this first, but didn't like any of these solutions, so I kept looking and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110921/1130636.

You can use `UrlParameter.Optional` to solve this problem

`Url.Action("Show", "Course", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional })`