# How to pass parameter in @url.Action

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have found this code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-danger"
    onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") +"'");">
Link
</button>
```

for redirecting- which is working fine,
But now I need to pass  parameter to this .
Please help.
Refereed the following [How do I redirect a user when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168577/how-do-i-redirect-a-user-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL.Action() including route values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107061/url-action-including-route-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sribin, below is fundamental which you can use,

your controller code will be,

```
 // GET: home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User uObject = new User();
        uObject.FirstName = "abc";
        return View(uObject);
    }

    public ActionResult IndexTest(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

your cshtml code will be

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<br />
<tr>
    <input type="button" onclick="SaveLookup()" value="submit" />

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-danger"
            onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("IndexTest", "Home", new {id = Model.FirstName}) +"'");">
        Link
    </button> 
</tr>
```

Instead of using model value you can grap value from view bag or any other tempdata too!!

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for

Comment: This is very basic fundamental of MVC. The initial learning steps so it might be happen they treat as a repeated query, common  and unlogical question. Don't worry you are right to ask, if you are at learning stage :)

Answer (score 0):

@Sribin, Try with below,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-danger"
        onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("IndexTest", "Home", new {id = "ID"}) +"'");">
    Link
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.instead of "ID"  how to pass dynamic values?

Comment: @Sribin you can send ID via controller